# Persistence on an online click once application

Tags: deployment, clickonce, persistence

Is there a way to persist an string from an online click once application. I saw something about isolated file storage as answers to other questions. But none of them specify if it works also for online apps (I really don't think so).

I think that something like a cookie will work. Is there something like that available?

The application must run only online (is triggered with some parameters), but for each user it needs to save a file with specific information asked to him. Once the app runs for the very first time it must not ask for that info to the user.

Thanks.

Comment: What's the problem with a cookie?

Comment: Is it plausible to create a cookie from this kind of app? I reed from here the opposite. 

Should I create it by using: HtmlDocument.Cookie?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the information in LocalApplicationData. Just create a directory with either your application name or your company name, stick the string in a file, and read it from there.